# Giant snails on a remote island

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

This story revolved around a guy who visited a remote island.  There were giant snails there and he thought it amusing and could easily out run them ... for a while.

Probably 50's.  Ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: In case the current answer doesn't work, what kind of story is it? Movie? Animation? TV show, serial or stand-alone? Black and white? Short story, novella, novel, illustrated, comic?

Comment: I remember a story like this in an issue of LOOK magazine from the mid-1960's. It had a full-page illustration of giant snails against a craggy, surrealistic landscape.

Comment: The accepted answer was published in the Saturday Evening Post in the mid 60s, perhaps you are mis-remembering the magazine?

Comment: There is Brisingir (2013?) Which has eregon rob from giant fish rating snails,  but probably not what you want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"[The Quest for Blank Claveringi](https://books.google.com/books?id=MahHv0FASmMC&pg=PT79&lpg=PT79&dq=%22The%20Quest%20for%20Blank%20Claveringi%22%20by%20Patricia%20Highsmith&source=bl&ots=F-ZvsCPcVd&sig=geF6_sQfT1VCHEfPqP2QbedNXhU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kiEcVZPHHOywsASFvYKIDQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Quest%20for%20Blank%20Claveringi%22%20by%20Patricia%20Highsmith&f=false)" by Patricia Highsmith. It's got everything you want, giant snails, remote islands, realizing too late that you're out of places to run...

[Complimentary ISFDB link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98146)

In my general spirit of explaining how I found an item, I remembered it from reading *Alfred Hitchcock's Supernatural Tales of Terror and Suspense* and that it had "blank" in the title, so I did a search for *short story killer snails blank* and the first match was a page discussing the story. Unfortunately, I don't remember what page that was, although [this review](https://billsyken.com/2015/05/18/eleven-by-patricia-highsmith-or-attack-of-the-killer-snails/) pops up first these days with the following summary:

> In that story, The Quest for Blank Claveringi, a man sails to an island in the South Pacific that is rumored to be home to giant snails. He wants to be the first to verify the giant snails’ existence and thus create a legacy for himself (his name is Avery Clavering, and he intents to name the snails after himself) . He gets to the uninhabited island, which is 3 miles by 1 mile, and it has tall trees but has been completely cleared of low-lying brush. After searching our hero finds a giant snail, about 25 feet high, asleep in a ravine, and he takes photos. The snail begins a slow pursuit of Clavering, and so after a while does a second snail, who has chewed through the line tethering his sailboat to the shore. The boat is a half-mile out to sea, and this guy is stuck on the island, and the snails are closing in. The chase goes on for days. The snails are slow, but they never stop.

Comment: If I recall correctly he gets caught at the end while crawling in exhaustion through a couple feet of water. - he then dies three ways at once!

Comment: @Danny3414: Just two. ""The snail made a splash as it entered the sea. To drown or to be eaten alive? the professor wondered. He was waist-deep when he stumbled, waist-deep but head under when the snail crashed down upon him, and he realized as the thousands of pairs of teeth began to gnaw at his back, that his fate was both to drown and to be chewed to death."

Comment: yeah that's right I remember now - I somehow thought he got crushed to death under it's massive weight as well, last read it about 1978

Comment: Well done. However, on the principle of not feeding the Googosaurus if we can help it, an ISFDB search brings up a chronological list of 58 English language short fiction titles containing "blank". No way to filter on snails or islands, but I bet you would have been able to pick out your title from the lineup.